# Dart: how to change the color of a button's text

Tags: html, css, dart

I'm really new to HTML and CSS and have been attempting to learn and use Dart for the last couple of days.  I'm now attempting to change the color of a button's text when a timer times out.

HTML

```
<button class="command-btn" type="button"
   id="calibrate-btn">Calibrate</button>
```

CSS

```
#calibrate-btn {
  color: black;
}
```

Dart

```
querySelector('#calibrate-btn').setAttribute('color','red');
```

I get no errors or warnings but the color does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the appearance using

```dart
querySelector('#calibrate-btn').style.color = 'red';
```

probably a better approach would be to add a style tag to your HTML or link an external *.css file and then just change the class in Dart like

```dart
querySelector('#calibrate-btn').classes.add('highlighted');
```